# How to display the output of an executed command line program?

Tags: java

I have a command line Java program which i unfortunately cannot modify for certain integrity reasons, I am providing a GUI for this program and i got it all covered except that i am unable to provide notifications about completion of processes to the user as the program prints data to command line using System.out.println() , I designed the UI using net beans and it resides in a separate file , so how can i do this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) to execute the program? Then you can get the output stream as well like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("java yourOtherProgram.jar");
InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
```

If you're calling some method directly, you could redirect System.out like this:

```
PrintStream out = ...;
PrintStream err = ...;

System.setOut(out);
System.setErr(err);

ThatOtherProgram foo = new ThatOtherProgram();
foo.main(new String[0]);
```

**EDIT**

You could then use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to scan the input and do something with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I re implemented the program using runtime.exec but i am still working on how to dynamically provide notifications based on the stream.. Thank you for your effort..

Comment: You could use the Scanner class to do that.